# Missing ClaimTypes.Upn in ClaimsPrinciple when user pass the federation authentication with Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

I followed below doc setup federation authentication with Azure AD Application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.2
However when I check the ClaimsPrinciple after I pass the authentication, I'm not able get Upn. Below are the claims returned in ClaimsPrinciple.

```
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: qOudzA1YRiA2iLS2E5OftrWh-ugM0tz4HBf2PBGF0GI}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: xxxx@xxxxx.com}
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname: xxxx}
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname: xxxx}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname: xxxx xxxx}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider: https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/x509}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences: http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/multipleauthn}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant: 2022-08-05T06:19:48.424Z}
```

The strange part is that If I use Azure AD authentication with this AAD application directly then I can get Upn. It looks like the Upn missing is related to Federation authentication. Is there anyway I can get the Upn with Federation authentication?